# Getting file path/name from an fd

Tags: node.js

I have a method that handles all errors that result from fs.write operations.
The method has an arg that is the fd of the file where the error occurred.

Is there a way I can retrieve the file path/name using the provided fd?

ie:

```
handleWriteError: function (fd, err) {
    // fetch the path/name using the fd, then:
    console.log('Error occurred writing to %s/%s', path, name);
}
```

using node v0.12

Answer (score 0):

File descriptor is an abstract indicator used to access a file or other input/output resource ( Usually non-negative integer ). Therefore you cannot get a file path or name from a descriptor object.

Example:

```
fs = require("fs");
fd = fs.openSync("readme.txt", "a");
console.dir(fd);
// 10
```